# Wie heißt der bayrische „Kochenball“?

Tags: single-word-request, proper-noun, culture

Ich habe gehört, dass es einen traditionellen Ball in Bayern gibt. Er heißt etwa „Kochenball“ und wird am Morgen gefeiert. Die Geschichte ist, dass der Ball für die Diener war, weil sie abends keine Zeit hatten und früh kochen mussten.

Google gibt aber kein Ergebnis für „Kochenball“. Wie heißt der Ball eigentlich?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Habe ein wenig experimentiert bei Google und den vermutlich von dir gesuchten Ball gefunden. Er heißt

**Kocherlball**

Das Suffix *-erl* ist übrigens eine Verkleinerungsform, die im süddeutschen Raum und in Österreich verbreitet ist. Unter einem *Achterl* versteht man beispielsweise in Wien ein (1/8 l) Glas Wein.

---

[Wikipedia-Eintrag zu Kocherlball](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kocherlball):

> Der Kocherlball ist eine an alte Traditionen anknüpfende Volkstanzveranstaltung, die einmal jährlich am dritten Sonntag im Juli von 6 bis 10 Uhr morgens am Chinesischen Turm im Englischen Garten in München stattfindet.
>
> […]
>
> Im 19. Jahrhundert (um 1880) trafen sich an jedem Sonntagmorgen (5 bis 8 Uhr) im Sommer in aller Frühe bei schönem Wetter bis zu 5000 Münchner Hausangestellte (Köchinnen, Laufburschen, Kindermädchen, Hausdiener usw.) zum Tanzen am Chinesischen Turm. Sie konnten sich nur ganz früh am Morgen treffen, da sie danach wieder arbeiten mussten. Im Jahre 1904 wurde die Veranstaltung aus „Mangel an Sittlichkeit“ von der Obrigkeit verboten.

[image: Kocherlball]

*(Foto-Quelle: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nicebastard/3734558936/ von NiceBastard)*

Comment: "die im süddeutschen Raum" - im süd*ost*deutschen Raum. Wer im Südwesten nach dem Suffix -rl sucht, wird ziemlich enttäuscht sein.